# prevent right click in wpf browser

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, contextmenu

I want to work with the WPF WebBrowser but the user can press right click to open new tabs e.g. I know that I need to disable the contextmenu but I only find solutions for the WinForms Webbrowser.

This is what I've tried: `webBrowser.ContextMenu.IsEnabled = false`

hope you can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it a while ago in WPF (got this code from another answer but I dont have the link for the question):

```
//Declare
private HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event documentEvents;

//Navigate to a Webpage and create a Eventhandler for LoadCompleted
webBrowser.Navigate(HTML);
webBrowser.LoadCompleted += webBrowser_LoadCompleted;

private void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   documentEvents = (HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)webBrowser.Document;
   documentEvents.oncontextmenu += webBrowser_ContextMenuOpening;
}

private bool webBrowser_ContextMenuOpening(IHTMLEventObj pEvtObj)
{
    return false;
}
```